# Stack Overflow for Teams not working today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Cannot access SO Teams today - see an "oops" message.

Is something going wrong?

> Page not found We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.
>
> Try searching for similar questions
>
> Browse our recent questions
>
> Browse our popular tags
>
> If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.

Comment: We're investigating a bad build.

Comment: Time for coffee I guess ...

Comment: Previous build has been deployed, we've identified the fix, will be going out shortly

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We've been building features for Teams and have been trickling feature changes into production. One particular feature needs changes to the hot path for Teams (in particular where we perform authorization checks) and we've been running through tests on it in our development environment for the past couple of days.

But we missed a deployment scenario - all our data was primed but we had an early exit when we thought the user didn't have any recently authenticated sessions. Except those are established on login and nobody on production had that data yet. Our default behaviour is to lock everything down if authorization breaks in any way; that's the behaviour you saw - we thought the session wasn't authorized and denied access.

We didn't pick this up in our dev environments because as we switch dev environments we tend to login and logout a lot which meant our sessions had all the data we were expecting.

To fix we've removed the early exit because, in this case, it doesn't make sense. Things are back as of about an hour ago and I'll be putting together a post-mortem tomorrow morning.

Apologies for the inconvenience.