# Is Stack Overflow for teams down today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm getting an HTTP 404 and what looks to be similar symptoms as [this past report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379881/stack-overflow-for-teams-not-working-today) from February while trying to access my teams instance:

[image]

Edit: This was for an already logged-in account. As answered in the previous report, if I logout and then log back in, I'm able to see my instance.

Comment: We're working on it. It should be back shortly.

Comment: Reading the answer for the referenced previous report actually helped me. If I re-login it works.

Comment: @MattR I bet it's related to [the search problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385825/search-in-main-meta-and-chat-isnt-working)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Earlier today we were doing some clean-up of some site settings that are used by both public Q&A and Teams. When the changes were pushed out, the public Q&A changes were successful, but the Teams build failed.

As a result, we ended up in an inconsistent state which took Teams offline. We pushed a build to Teams again which put things in the correct state and things came back online.

Comment: I always like to hear _why_ things broke. So much more interesting than "we found the bug and fixed it".

Comment: @Clonkex Indeed. When a company don't explain it, you get that concerning feeling of "what horrible thing happened that they don't want to disclose it"?

Comment: @totymedli Actually, Tim lost his keys again and accidentally deleted the Teams database. Taryn just makes up these explanations to make us feel better.