# Search in main, meta and chat isn't working

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

The search either on Stack Overflow chat, Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow isn't working.

Errors "workin on ur problemz" are present when trying to search in chat and there are no results regardless of the keyword searched in both main and meta, here.

What's going on?

Comment: Wait, there's a functional search on SO? Why didn't anyone tell me about it?

Comment: Yes, @Machavity, it's called Google, using `site:https://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: We're investigating.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search should be back online now. We pushed a configuration change to ElasticSearch to enable [Search Slow Logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/index-modules-slowlog.html) and there was an issue with the change.

We rolled back the config change and will do further testing before pushing it again.